# How to update weights in Bayesian neural network

Tags: bayesian, neural-networks

If I understand correctly, in BNN, we compute posterior and this becomes our new prior(new updated weights). But the problem I don't understand is, how do you update new weights, since unlike in deterministic neural network, you don't update point estimate. If I understand correctly, you need to apply new mu and sigma parameters on weights (if gaussian is the case).

I would appreciate your reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only for the trivial problems you can apply Bayes theorem directly to calculate the posterior distributions. For almost all real-life statistical problems we use algorithms for *approximating* the posterior distribution. Currently the most popular approach to this is using Markov Chain Monte Carlo (see questions tagged as [mcmc](/questions/tagged/mcmc)), for example the NUTS sampler ([Hoffman and Gellman, 2011](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4246)). Since for Bayesian neural networks those algorithms may be inefficient because of the huge number of parameters, in such cases people often use [variational inference](https://krasserm.github.io/2019/03/14/bayesian-neural-networks/) (see [variational-bayes](/questions/tagged/variational-bayes)), with algorithms like ADVI ([Kucukelbir et al, 2016](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.00788)) to estimate the posterior distributions. This is dynamically changing field, with a lot of ongoing research on this subject, and many more algorithms were proposed in the literature, so it is hard to summarise it in Q&A site answer. Moreover, it is plausible that the methods that are popular in this field today, would not be that popular in a year or two, since we would find better algorithms. I would encourage you to google for ["bayesian neural networks"](https://www.google.com/search?q=bayesian%20neural%20networks), since this would reveal thousands of relevant search results including academic papers, books, online tutorials, recordings of conference talks etc. on this subject.